# Cryptic remark in physics revision guide

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, conventions

I am currently revising for my AP physics and I couldn't understand one of the end-of-section summary notes. It says: "Remember that the direction of magnetic field is from North to South, and that the current is from positive to negative."

I understand the magnetic field part, but I don't understand "current is from positive to negative".

Doesn't current flow from the *negative* terminal of a battery to the *positive* terminal? Or are they speaking about conventional current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are obviously talking about "conventional" current, not the flow of electrons. When you want to know the direction of magnetic force on a current you need to use "conventional" current direction.

There is an interesting corollary to this relating to the Hall effect - if current in a semiconductor is carried by "holes" the polarity of the Hall effect is opposite to that which you get if it is carried by electrons. If you don't understand this last sentence you don't need to worry... It may not be on your syllabus. Good luck on the exam!

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear! I will need the good luck :)